DB Super Sparpreis Europa cancellation help
I have a trip this coming Friday and the original itinerary was:

However looking into the DB navigator I see that the trip has been cancelled. When I click to search alternatives, it gives  me a blank page, but looking at the same route the trip appears, but now starting at 6.15 am and with the same trains:


I should then be able to get into this trip using both trains (the same as the one cancelled), no? Is there something else I should do or would the same QR code just work?

I've been plagued by the same thing -  I get an email about my trip being "cancelled" and I must find alternatives. But when I click on alternatives, it can't find any. I then just repeat my original search and find an alternative (usually involving my original train).

You should be fine.
That is indeed somewhat strange, I have no idea why this is shown as "cancelled" and with no alternatives. The itinerary is available to be booked for tomorrow and the only thing that appears to have changed is the departure time.
It's probably a glitch in their system. If there is a real cancellation, any type of "Zugbindung" (ticket tied to a specific train) would be voided and you are free to take any can take any train to your destination on the same day including your original train.


DB are usually poor in their communication in case of travel changes.  In my experience, whenever there is the slightest change, they tell you that your trip is cancelled and you have to find an alternative route.  That might just be one of your trains departing two minutes earlier or later.
In your case, it seems like you can still travel from Berlin to Praha and from Praha to Kraków.  However, in case you use the "use any train" right internationally, I strongly recommend you take a screenshot of the page saying so.  I have previously had discussions with conductors in Switzerland who said that whatever restrictions DB lift are only lifted for DB trains and not SBB trains on the same ticket.  I don't know how ČD or PKP handle this.

That shouldn't be a problem here is OP is planning to take the exact same trains they originally booked.

The Zugbindung on Sparpreis Europa tickets is generally only applicable in Germany, but not outside. The only exceptions from this rule are Italy, the Netherlands and Switzerland.

@Inconspicuousseagull Are you sure?  The Danish railways have similar systems, so I'd be surprised if a Sparpreis to Copenhagen does not have Zugbindung in Denmark.

As an update my original ticket and QR code worked fine. As a refresher I took a train from Leipzig to Prague and another from Prague to Krakow. In botj trips I had a ticket control and showed them the "cancelled" one and not a question was asked. I would assume it is a glitch in the system of DB.

@gerrit you can find the conditions applying to Sparpreis Europa tickets in the SCIC-NRT document published by DB. According to section 5.2.3, "Zugbindung" only applies on legs operated by DB. The SCIC-SB can specify deviations from this rule, but in case of the Sparpreis Europa Dänemark, it does not.
